# BuildNotContainsExpression causes System.StackOverflowException with large data set on Windows 7 -64-bit

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, stack-overflow

I have encountered a condition where my app crashes with a particular dataset on Windows 7, 64-bit.  All other platforms work fine on the same dataset.  I have determined that my app is crashing in the BuildNotContainsExpression that many people have posted.

Is there a way for the expression to be built using memory from the heap?
Should I just break done my usersActive list and process smaller chunks at a time (like 1000)?
Something else?

```
List<int> usersActive = myContext.myTable.Select(a => a.tableUsersSnapshot.id).Distinct().ToList();
// The code blows up (only on Win7 64-bit) on this line when usersActive is large ~4000
// (probably will blow up on all platforms if usersActive is sufficiently large)
expTest = CustomExpressions.BuildNotContainsExpression<tableUsersSnapshot, int>(a => a.id, usersActive);
List<tableUsersSnapshot> usersToDelete = myContext.myTableSnapshot.Where(expTest).ToList();
// Delete the objects in the delete list
foreach(tableUsersSnapshot user in usersToDelete)
{
    myContext.DeleteObject(user);
}
```

Edit:  Here's the BuildNotContains function - it is not recursive:

```
public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildNotContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
    {  
        if (null == valueSelector) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");}
        if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

        ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();

        // p => valueSelector(p) != values[0] && valueSelector(p) != ...

        if (!values.Any())
        {
            return e => true;
        }

        var equals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.NotEqual(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));
        var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => Expression.And(accumulate, equal));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
    }
```

Here's the applicable portion of my EDMX diagram:
[image]

Comment: Required comment for StackOverflow in question name :)

Comment: What does BuildNotContains look like? It sounds recursive, but I can't think of a reason for it to be such.

Comment: Also, does `where !someArray.Contains(a.Id)` not work in EF? I would expect it to work in LINQ-to-SQL...

Comment: The Contains didn't work for me in EF, thus the "jumping through hoops" by building the expression.

Answer (score 0):

EF 4 doesn't require `BuildContainsExpression`, are you using an earlier version?

It looks like you are trying to join two tables to find missing Ids but you are doing it all client-side instead of on SQL server.

Instead, use a join between the two tables to find the table snapshots that don't have a corresponding user.  See for example http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx

If you had an FK relationship between your two tables you could select the records to delete using a simple ! .Any(...) clause.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 which I believe is EF 3.5.  I will look at your example.  I'm a firmware engineer by nature trying to learn this database stuff as I go.  So far I've gotten things to work, even if they aren't the most efficient.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your last statement?  The first table I query (shown as myTable in original question) does contain a FK to the usersSnapshot table.

Comment: If you have an association this could be something simple like `myContext.myTableSnapshot.Where(ts => !ts.myTable.Any())`.  Posting your EDMX diagram would help.  EF went from V1 to V4.  If you aren't using V4 I highly recommend switching if you can.

Comment: I've uploaded the EDMX diagram.  I'd like to switch but I think it's too close to release time.  That is too big of a risk right now.